# How do I make my matrix object implicitly convert to scalar when its dimensions are 1x1?

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading, member-functions

I have written a `Matrix` class. It does multiplications between matrices. Sometimes multiplication of matrices yield a 1x1 matrix (e.g.; inner product of two column vectors). Is it possible to make a `Matrix` object directly return a scalar value when it is one-by-one?

```
template <class T> class Matrix
{
    public:
        // ...
        T&       operator()(uint64_t unRow, uint64_t unCol = 0) throw(MatrixOutOfRange);
        const T& operator()(uint64_t unRow, uint64_t unCol = 0) const throw(MatrixOutOfRange);
        // ...
    protected:
        std::vector<T> MatrixArray;
        // ...
};

// ...

template <class T>
T & Matrix<T>::operator()(uint64_t unRow, uint64_t unCol /*= 0*/) throw(MatrixOutOfRange)
{
    /* Bound checking here */
    return MatrixArray[m_unColSize * unRow + unCol];
}

template <class T>
const T & Matrix<T>::operator()(uint64_t unRow, uint64_t unCol /*= 0*/) const throw(MatrixOutOfRange)
{
    /* Bound checking here */
    return MatrixArray[m_unColSize * unRow + unCol];
}

// ...
```

---

Example code:

[image: Latex image]

```
Matrix<double> A (3, 1,    1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
Matrix<double> AT(1, 3,    1.0, 2.0, 3.0);   // Transpose of the A matrix
Matrix<double> B (3, 1,    4.0, 5.0, 6.0);
Matrix<double> C();

C = AT * B;
double Result1 = C(0, 0);
double Result2 = (AT * B)(0, 0);
double Result3 = A.InnerProductWith(B)(0, 0);
```

I want to drop the unnecessary element location specifier arguments `(0, 0)` when the result is a one-by-one matrix. Like this:

```
C = AT * B;
double Result1 = C;
double Result2 = AT * B;
double Result3 = A.InnerProductWith(B);
```

It is OK if it throws an exception if the result is not one-by-one.

Comment: This is possible but most definitely a Bad Idea.

Comment: `C` is a function (that you never defined) that takes no arguments and returns a `Matrix<double>`.  For a default constructed object, leave off the parentheses.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley is referring to the line `Matrix<double> C();`.  It's a deceptive parse.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

This would work similarly to [`std::vector::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), which is also a compile-time call that will always throw unless certain runtime conditions are met.

A conversion operator to type `T` would look like this:

```
template <class T> class Matrix
{
    public:
        // ...
        operator T &() { 
           // Throw here if size is not 1x1...

           return (*this)( 0, 0 ); 
        }

        operator T const &() const { 
           // Throw here if size is not 1x1...

           return (*this)( 0, 0 ); 
        }
        // ...
};
```

All your example code would work, as-written.

Comment: But the matrix's size is not part of the type, so this conversion would be present for matrices of all sizes.

Comment: @juanchopanza that's correct, and a bit unsavory, but it was explicitly part of the question.  *"It is OK if it throws an exception if the result is not one-by-one."*

Comment: `operator T &()` and `operator T const &() const` would better match the semantics of `operator()` indexing.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Yes, I should have done that!  Now syntax like `myMatrix1x1 = 0.0` is also valid.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless the size becomes part of the type. Else, you will have to either always have a scalar conversion, or never. You cannot change the type's *compile-time* features (whether or not it has an implicit conversion) based on a *run-time* fact- whether the size is 1 in both dimensions or not. That would require precognition on the part of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do this would be to make your sizes part of the type:

```
template <class T, size_t NRows, size_t NCols>
class Matrix
{
public:
    // ...
protected:
    // ...
    T M_storage[NRows][NCols]; // Or something...
};
```

Then use template specialization to add the conversion operator to the 1x1 Matrix:

```
template <class T>
class Matrix<T, 1, 1>
{
public:
    // ...
    operator T ()
    {
       return M_storage;//[0][0]; 
    }
protected:
    // ...
    //T M_storage[1][1]; // Or something...
    // Or even
    T M_storage;
};
```

Comment: Would be safer to use CRTP to add the feature without rewriting the whole `Matrix` class.

Comment: An even better idea might be to have both types (Fixed and Flex Matrix).  Implicit conversion only works for `Fixed<1,1,T>`.  Flex has a member function to convert to scalar.  Fixed is implemented in terms of Flex, but also gives you size guarantees at compile time.  Oh, and while you are at it, `[]` is to get elements out (either `[a,b,...]` or `[a][b][...]`), `()` is to evaluate as a linear function on an argument.